# How to receive handle of second Monitor / Desktop

Tags: .net, api, screen, desktop, monitor

I found the default desktop function
[`GetDesktopWindow` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633504.aspx)

What how to catch the result for a second monitor?

*** EDIT SOLVED ***

```
<Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", 
CharSet:=Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling:=True)> _
Public Shared Function WindowFromPoint(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) 
As IntPtr
End Function
```

Did the trick.

Comment: A Monitor is not a desktop. It could be part of a desktop.

Comment: Thats true. But the GetDesktopWindow is used to receive data for `GetDeviceCaps` and returns wrong handle for using of the second monitor. But I solved it now. Thanks for your information.

Comment: But how did you know what x and y to give it so you get the second monitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", 
CharSet:=Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling:=True)> _
Public Shared Function WindowFromPoint(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) 
As IntPtr
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`Screen` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx) (Windows Forms) could help dealing with multiple monitors.

I.e. use the [`Screen.AllScreens` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens.aspx) to enumerate all monitors.

Comment: No, because I can not receive the handle there as far as I read the documentation.